# How can I create a custom band-pass filter?

Tags: image-processing, filter

In [this research paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1155/2010/680429), in the Section 4.1(Preprocessing), an equation of a Bandpass filter is given:

[image]

Where,

[image]

Now, I have implemented this like the following:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZhucE2

But, this code produces nothing.

Comment: What exactly do you not know how to do? I looked at the documentation of [`Mat` class](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)

Comment: the filter is frequency domain but a `Mat` obj generally holds the image in non-frequency domain. You have to take the 2D fft of the image, multiply image with the filter and take the inverse 2D fft to get the image back in spatial coordinates.

Comment: do you need more detailed info?

Comment: were you able to get it to work?

Comment: meaning you didn't get to it or need more detailed info?

Comment: do you have access to Matlab? Even if the final solution has to be in .NET, it's helpful to use if your math is correct. And you can easily output the Matlab 2-D array in `.csv` format and easily compare with the final - and intermediate - outputs with your code. That's how I used to debug DSP algorithms.

Comment: I'm not sure of the frequency mapping: when you have a 2D image and you take 2D fft, the zero-zero frequency index is NOT in the bottom left but at (mid_x, mid_y). So, I'm not sure if your filter transfer function takes that into account.

Comment: Ok I just realized that it does: via the parameters center_x, center_y, and theta.

Comment: Assuming you simply do fft_image = fft2(image), your (tx, ty) are the midpoints of your image ie mid_x, mid_y

Comment: Another complication is that the filter is in analog format (I think). I need to think if simply sampling it is correct and if so how to do it correctly.

Comment: I'm 75% that it's ok to simply sample the filter to get a 2D digital representation. Be sure though to sample it at the same intervals that your image is sampled at. Unfortunately I don't know what that interval should be!

Comment: I think you need to find the digital form of the analog filter.

Comment: you probably need to know what u,v mean in the definition of the filter

Comment: Then you can directly use the filter functions to compute a 2D array which contains filter values for each combination of frequency coordinates.

Comment: Agree with @Trilarion. This was done in my implementation in these lines :  `for u in range(0, size[0]):
    for v in range(0, size[1]):
        kernel[u][v] = K.H_Function(Dh, Dv, u, v, centerX, centerY, theta, n) `

Comment: @Trilarion @taarraas problem is: What are the units of `Dh` and `Dv`? Digital frequency response is only unique over a `2pi` range. [slide 6](http://www.eas.uccs.edu/~mwickert/ece2610/lecture_notes/ece2610_chap6.pdf)

Comment: @Adrian Dh an Dv set frequency, which you want to extract. Theta sets orientation. Some intuition behind this. In Section 4.1 of article they use filter to extract lines on the image, that's why kernel is also looks like a line, so scalar multiplication with image will give high response at points on a line. In spatial domain Dh and Dv sets the width of this line (large width - lower frequency). And theta of kernel should match angle of the detected line on image.

Comment: I suggest to use Dh and Dv the same value, and try different values with step x2, like 1, 2, 4, 8 .... Center is kernel_width/2, kernel_height/2. n is curvature of you filter, higher n somehow increases frequency, and make the kernel boundaries sharper (faster growing).

Comment: You should multiply fft of image by fft of function H.

Comment: function H is a kernel of filter

Comment: Removing `C#` tag as answer is agnostic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create image of your kernel, then to convolve it with your image. fft is used for optimization of convolution for large images. You can use filter2D function to make opencv do everything for you.

Kernel image:
[image]
Source image:
[image: Source image]
Convolution applied:
[image]
Trhesholding:
[image]

Please see code below:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

class Kernel(object):
    def H_Function(self, Dh, Dv, u, v, centerX, centerY, theta, n):
        return 1 / (1 + 0.414 * math.sqrt(math.pow(self.U_Star(u, centerX, centerY, theta) / Dh + self.V_Star(v, centerX, centerY, theta) / Dv, 2 * n)))

    def U_Star(self, u, centerX, centerY, theta):
        return math.cos(theta) * (u + self.Tx(centerX, theta)) + math.sin(theta) * (u + self.Ty(centerY, theta))

    def V_Star(self, u, centerX, centerY, theta):
        return (-math.sin(theta)) * (u + self.Tx(centerX, theta)) + math.cos(theta) * (u + self.Ty(centerY, theta))

    def Tx(self, center, theta):
        return center * math.cos(theta)

    def Ty(self, center, theta):
        return center * math.sin(theta)

K = Kernel()

size = 40, 40
kernel = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.float)
Dh=2
Dv=2
centerX = -size[0] / 2
centerY = -size[1] / 2
theta=0.9
n=4

for u in range(0, size[0]):
    for v in range(0, size[1]):
        kernel[u][v] = K.H_Function(Dh, Dv, u, v, centerX, centerY, theta, n) 
kernelNorm = np.copy(kernel)
cv2.normalize(kernel, kernel, 1.0, 0, cv2.NORM_L1)
cv2.normalize(kernelNorm, kernelNorm, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
cv2.imwrite("kernel.jpg", kernelNorm)

imgSrc = cv2.imread('src.jpg',0)

convolved = cv2.filter2D(imgSrc,-1,kernel)
cv2.normalize(convolved, convolved, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
cv2.imwrite("conv.jpg", convolved)
th, thresholded = cv2.threshold(convolved, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite("thresh.jpg", thresholded)
```

Comment: What is the problem with this solution?

Comment: @anonymous so you don't care about visualizing the filter or any intermediate step?

Comment: @Adrian if you think there is something wrong with visualization, could you please explain?

Comment: @taarraas I'm not saying your answer is not good. I don't have enough Python experience to eyeball your code and determine correctness.

Comment: @Adrian but one doesn't need a degree to read python code. Just... lookup the Numpy functions, the rest is straightforward.

Comment: @ulidtko i'm not 100% sure this is the correct way to apply this filter. It's in analog form and you need its digital form to apply to an image. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Adrian What do you mean by analog form? PC doesn't work directly with analog form of signal, it converts analog signal to digital form to process. Both kernel and input image are digital and discrete.

Comment: @taarraas asked how to apply a certain filter. That filter appears to be in analog form but maybe it's not. If it is an analog filter, you have to find its digital form.

Comment: @taarraas as for the kernel idea: I don't know what that is. You def have more experience with image filtering.

Comment: @Adrian and this is what was done by calculating it values in finite discrete number of points while constructing kernel 40x40 variable

Comment: @taarraas, what is the source of your kernel image? The original paper doesn't talk about any such image

Comment: @anonymous It's your function H. pixel with coordinates (u, v) on image is value of H(u,v)

Comment: @taarraas, as far as I knew, kernels are either another image or a matrix of some predefined numbers. Here, we don't have another image and in order to build a matrix using H(u,v), we first need to obtain (u,v)s. So, how am I obtaining those values?

Comment: @anonymous You don't neet to obtain them. You just need to sample this function. for(int i=0 ; i<imageWidth ; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
                {
                    kernel2D[i, j] = (double)KassWitkin.ApplyFilterOnOneCoord(i, j, Dh, Dv, CenterX, CenterY, Theta, N);
                }
            }

Comment: @taarraas, so, the size of the kernel is becoming the same as the image dimensions. Then, how did u set the size of the kernel in your code to 40x40?

Comment: @anonymous It more depends on implementation. Usually it makes sense to limit size of kernel image to boundaries, where it has large values. Larger kernel image - slower convolving. For fft it's not that critical, but without fft the complexity is O(imgPixelCnt * kernelPixelCnt), so it grows as square of kernel side. I use 40x40 because it's minimal filter size which has all necessary information. Just be sure that centerX and centerY is center of your kernel, not image.

Comment: @anonymous read this on convolutions : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution

Comment: @anonymous and this for optimization of convolution using fft : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms

Comment: @anonymous and this to understand idea of filtering : http://www.roborealm.com/help/Convolution.php

Comment: @taarraas, did you perceive the kernel formula in the spatial domain or frequency domain?

Comment: @anonymous in spatial domain

Comment: @taarraas, but the formula seems to be in Frequency domain, right?

Comment: @taarraas, Your implementation worked, I guess, because you normalized the 2d array.

Comment: Why do you think it's in frequency domain?

Comment: @taarraas, who is Adrian?

Answer (score 3):

There is no real need to store the filter in an array. You can just perform a double loop on the u, v components for the values at which the FFT was evaluated, compute the filter response H(u, v) for every couple and multiply that to the corresponding array element. After reverse transformation of the modifed array, you'll get the filtered image.

Comment: @anonymous: sorry, I am not a free coding service.

Comment: I wonder what troubles you. Taking the FFT is a simple function call. Multiplying array elements by the evaluation of H(u, v) is immediate. Taking the inverse FFT also a function call. So what ?