# Apply a filter bank in parallel

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge, accord.net, filter-bank

I am using Accord.NET framework.

Suppose, I have three Gabor filters, and, I need to apply them to an image in parallel.

Is the following a correct concept of a parallel Filter Bank?

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Lenna.png");

GaborFilter gf1 = new GaborFilter();
gf1.GaborKernelSize = 3;
gf1.Lambda = 4.0;
gf1.Theta = 45.0;////////////////////Theta is 45
gf1.Psi = 1.0;
gf1.Sigma = 2.0;
gf1.Gamma = 0.3;

GaborFilter gf2 = new GaborFilter();
gf2.GaborKernelSize = 3;
gf2.Lambda = 4.0;
gf2.Theta = 90.0;/////////////////////Theta is 90
gf2.Psi = 1.0;
gf2.Sigma = 2.0;
gf2.Gamma = 0.3;

GaborFilter gf3 = new GaborFilter();
gf3.GaborKernelSize = 3;
gf3.Lambda = 4.0;
gf3.Theta = 135.0;////////////////////Theta is 135
gf3.Psi = 1.0;
gf3.Sigma = 2.0;
gf3.Gamma = 0.3;

bmp = gf1.Apply(bmp);
bmp = gf2.Apply(bmp);
bmp = gf3.Apply(bmp);

MyWinForm f = new MyWinForm ();
f.PictureBox = bmp;
f.ShowDialog();
```

If not, then, how can I make them work in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filter bank is just a set of filters each one with different parameters which aims to get a response for different component of the signal.

In your case, Gabor filters, the parameters that you change is the orientation so each one of the filters will give the response of the features in the image with the selected orientation. For a filter bank of size N (N different filters) if we apply it to an image we would get N different images each one is the result of a specific filter.

In your code you apply the filters one after the other were the output of the first filter is the input for the next one. In this case you can't filter the image in parallel.

Applying a Gabor fitler is just a convolution of a Gabor kernel with the image. Therefore Instead of applying each Gabor filter on the image separately you can just convolve the Gabor filters together and get a new filter which than can be applied once on the entire image.

Comment: Would it work if I apply the filter bank to images to obtain 03 images and then merge them by applying AND operations?

Comment: When you filter the image you don't get a binary result so i don't think you can do AND operation. I don't know what exactly you want to achieve if you will tell me maybe i could help.

Comment: I am just trying to create a bank of oriented band-pass filters. That Gabor source code was just an example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769350/how-can-i-create-a-custom-band-pass-filter

Comment: The bank itself i just the collection of the filters. If you would threshold each filter response and than use AND operation you will get all the pixels that have a very high orientation response in all the directions you used. If this is your goal yes you can apply them in parallel (using a thread for each one of the filters) and than threshold the results and use an AND operation.

Comment: If you would have please provided me some sample code, it would have been very helpful.

Comment: I am not a .net gay so i can't help with the code. On how to use threads in c# refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx. Good luck